# Excel VBA code is not working because of a syntax error

Tags: excel, vba, if-statement

I'm using the following code to check if a cell contains the word 'saturday' or 'sunday'. If yes I want to add text in some other cells. When I execute the code Excel freezes (I think it's stuck in the loop?).

```
Sub sbFORMAT()

'delete all shiftdata
Sheets("ploegregeling").Activate

Range("ploeginput").UnMerge
Range("ploeginput").ClearContents
Range("ploeginput").ClearComments


'color weekends blue (= add W in cell, conditional formatting adds blue color + text)

Dim dag As Integer
Dim rij As Integer
Dim rij2 As Integer
Dim rij3 As Integer

dag = 3
rij = 5

Do Until dag = 33

rij2 = rij + 2
rij3 = rij2 + 17

If Cells(dag, rij).Value = "Saturday" Or Cells(dag, rij).Value = "Sunday" Then Range("Cells(dag, rij2), Cells(dag, rij3)").Value = "W"

dag = dag + 1

Loop


End Sub
```

[image: The Excel sheets looks like this]

The code should add `W` in every cell in the range `G7:G24,H7:H24,N7:N24`, etc.
By writing `W` in the cell it will then turn blue (conditional formatting). This is working by doing it manually.

Comment: I could be wring but you're not incrementing "dag" ... if that's the case, it will loop forever.

Comment: Doesn't look like your Do loop modifies the value of the dag variable.

Comment: Thank you for commenting. I indeed forgot to increment "dag" . Stupid me. I tried again and now its giving me a range error (= Then Range("Cells(dag, rij2), Cells(dag, rij3)").Value = "W" )

Comment: Your cells should not be in quotes. Try: `Range(Cells(dag, rij2), Cells(dag, rij3)).Value`

Comment: Mathias, please change the title of your question as it is now misleading.

Comment: That was it. Also "dag" and "rij" were switched around... Thanks everyone for helping.